# Not able to center text in android canvas

Tags: android, canvas, paint

I am using following code to write "g" inside a circle. "g" must be centered horizontally and vertically inside the circle. But I am not able to, where am I wrong ?

```
//sv is surfaceview which covers whole screen
sv.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() 
    {

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // surfaceview width
            swidth=sv.getWidth();
            sheight=sv.getHeight();
            int height = sheight/3;
            int mat = Math.min(height,swidth/2);
            Paint paint= new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            Paint paint1= new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            Resources r = getResources();
            paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
            paint1.setColor(Color.BLACK);

            Canvas c = sv.getHolder().lockCanvas();
            c.drawARGB(254, 254, 254, 254);
            String t1="g";
            int ttwidth=determineMaxTextSize(t1, mat/4);
            paint1.setTextSize(ttwidth);
            Rect bounds = new Rect();
            paint1.getTextBounds(t1, 0, 3, bounds);
            c.drawCircle(swidth/4, height+height/2, mat/4, paint);
            c.drawText(t1, swidth/4-bounds.width()/2, height+height/2+bounds.height()/2, paint1);



            sv.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);

        }
```

This is the method used in above code.

```
private int determineMaxTextSize(String str, float maxWidth)
{
    int size = 0;       
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    do {
        paint.setTextSize(++ size);
    } while(paint.measureText(str) < maxWidth);

    return size;
}
```

Here is what I get when I try 4 different texts.

[image]

**EDIT:**
After editing my code with this

```
            paint1.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
            String t1="N";
            int ttwidth=determineMaxTextSize(t1, mat/4);
            paint1.setTextSize(ttwidth);
            Rect bounds = new Rect();
            paint1.getTextBounds(t1, 0, 3, bounds);
            c.drawCircle(swidth/4, height+height/2, mat/4, paint);
            c.drawText(t1, swidth/4, height+height/2+bounds.height()/2, paint1);
```

I get this outcome which is better
[image]

However, you can see "g" is still not aligned.

Comment: not matter what text i choose it is still not properly centered

Comment: Where is it? Can you take a screenshot and show us what is actually being drawn where

Comment: you can save some complicated calculation if you set `paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER)`

Comment: @zgc7009 done the update

Comment: Might want to try, just looking at how it looks visually, trying to change your portion of drawText to swidth/4-bounds.width() instead of swidth/4-bounds.width()/2

Comment: @hgoebl you were correct, your solution helped me to improve the result, please see the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 paint1.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
        String t1="N";
        int ttwidth=determineMaxTextSize(t1, mat/4);
        paint1.setTextSize(ttwidth);
        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        paint1.getTextBounds(t1, 0, 3, bounds);
        c.drawCircle(swidth/4, height+height/2, mat/4, paint);
        c.drawText(t1, swidth/4, height+height/2+bounds.height()/2, paint1);
```

Above code is the answer